# What will happen if I Power-ON RPI simultaneously from GPIO Header Power pins and Micro USB?

Tags: gpio, power, rpi.gpio

What will happen if I Power-ON RPI simultaneously from GPIO Power pins and Micro USB?

For RPI1,RPI2 & RPI3

Comment: I have no idea.  I suggest you don't do it though, unless you are very sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: If you're using a single power supply and splitting it to the 5V rail pins and the micro USB socket, I don't *think* it'll be a problem (but I still wouldn't try it on my own Pi). If you use separate supplies you're [likely to have some issues](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/245913/80270) due to the voltage mismatch between them.

Comment: Don't do that. It doesn't do the Pi any good.

Comment: Be careful, the 5V pin bypasses the regulator, and don't forget to "common ground", related post using wall wart and batteries [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerBatteries)

Comment: Beyond the warnings above, why would you want to do this?

Comment: If I am powering ON my PI from the HAT through GPIO header(Default).Accidentally PI was already also powered through Micro USB.